# Probability with replacement (two cases)

Tags: probability, solution-verification

If in a box there are 5 red balls and 3 blues balls, so the probability to take out 2 balls from a box (with replacement) such that 1 are red and 1 is blue is:
$$P=\frac{5}{8}\cdot\frac{3}{8}+\frac{3}{8}\cdot\frac{5}{8}$$
because I have two cases: the first ball is the red one or the first ball is the blue one.

Am I right?

Comment: You said you are drawing $3$ balls but you are finding the probability for $2$ balls....

Comment: @ShubhamJohri my mistake! I just edited it.

Comment: Your answer is right